# How to burn the tokens treasury gets from staking inefficiency?

Tags: pallet-treasury, pallet-staking

the main point is in the question itself.

Let's assume the `inflation rate` varies `between 1% and 10%`. However, in the end, the inflation will always be 10%. In this [link](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-treasury#funding-the-treasury), you can find reasons for why it has been designed this way.

I'm curious about the most efficient method to modify this behavior so that what comes from the staking pallet is burned, with as few changes as possible. I assume we need to modify this in the staking pallet:
`type RewardRemainder = Treasury;`

But I'm unsure about the replacement. Should it be `()`? Or should we create a struct with a custom `OnUnbalanced` implementation? Or perhaps there's another solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/staking#era-payout)):

> The remaining reward is send to the configurable end-point T::RewardRemainder.

You can set it to `()` ([implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/imbalance/on_unbalanced.rs#L55)) which will result in its
["default" implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/imbalance/on_unbalanced.rs#L32-L53) => burning everything. You can also create a struct with a
custom implementation ([example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1835c091c42456e8df3ecbf0a94b7b88c395f623/substrate/frame/staking/src/mock.rs#L218-L227)).